# NodeJS passport + postgre

Tags: node.js, passport, express

Я в nodejs совсем новенький и пытаюсь создать авторизацию.
Смотрел кучу документаций, но так и не понял как прикрутить к пасспорту запрос в базу postgre, дабы проверить на наличие аккаунта и подтвердить пароль.

Что сейчас имею:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'ogrn',
    passwordField: 'okpo'
},
function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({username : username}, function(err, user) {
        return err 
            ? done(err)
            : user
                ? password === user.password
                    ? done(null, user)
                    : done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password.'})
                : done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username.'});
    });
}));
```

Вот и кто мне может объяснить, как сделать в данном фрагменте запрос к базе? Или это как-то прикручивается раньше, не смог понять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте предположим, что вы не используете ORM для взаимодействия с базой данных.

Асинхронная функция получения пользователя из базы данных PostgreSQL может иметь вид:

```
// fetch_user.js
var pg = require('pg');

module.exports = fetchUser = function (username, done) {
    // Создаем клиента базы данных. По-хорошему, здесь вы должны использовать
    // пул соединений, заранее сконфигурированный и передваемый 
    // "из вне". Для простоты я использую одиночного клиента БД.
    var client = new pg.Client();

    // Устанавливаем соединение с БД.
    client.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // Ошибка подключения. Возвращаем ее на уровень выше.
            return done(err);
        }

        // Отправляем запрос в базу.
        client.query(
            'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1::text',
            [username],
            function (err, results) {
                // Закрываем соединение с БД.
                client.end();
                // Возвращаем ошибку или результат запроса.
                // Если пользователь не найден, возвращаем null вместо данных.
                done(err, result.rows[0] || null);
            }
        );
    });
};
```

А вот так ее можно использовать:

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    fetchUser = require('./fetch_user.js');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'ogrn',
    passwordField: 'okpo'
},
function(username, password, done) {
    fetchUser(username, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username.'});
        }

        // По-хорошему, в базе вы должны хранить хэш пароля. А раз так, то
        // переменную "password" стоит захешировать перед сравнением.
        if (user.password !== password) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password.'});
        }

        done(null, user);
    });
}));
```